# What is the meaning of this sqrt=x**0.5?

Tags: python

```
import math

def countSquares(x):
    sqrt=x**0.5
    result=int(sqrt)
    return result
x=81
print(countSquares(x))
```

Comment: [power operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator)

Answer (score 1):

x**0.5 is "x to the power of 0.5" which essentially means square root of x.